# Chrome 83 dev tools Network Preview tab is blank when it should be showing a formatted JSON response

Tags: json, ajax, google-chrome-devtools

When I inspect an XHR JSON response in Chrome dev tools, the Response tab shows the returned information, but the Preview tab is blank, even though the response headers declare "application/json" as the content-type.

Here is a screenshot of the Headers tab making a request to [api.particle.io](https://api.particle.io), verifying the response header content-type:

[image]

Here is the Preview tab for that same request's response (and showing my Chrome version):

[image: (]

And finally, here is the Response tab showing the unformatted JSON response:

[image]

I've tried setting up my own server and returning JSON payloads with different response header content-types but to no avail.

Comment: Sounds like https://crbug.com/1073822 - see comment 7 there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem resolved by allowing JavaScript on all sites:

[image]

Open issue detailed here: [crbug.com/1073822](https://crbug.com/1073822) as noted by @wOxxOm.